# It is possible to track .png/.jpeg link access with google analytics?

Tags: image, google-analytics, tracking

I have a site that provides images for the internet, and I have Google analytics implemented, but is only tracing the pages access and not the link access, like this example:

You can access an image o http://doamin.com/aa and it shows an html page with a template and the image implemented.

And A want, if possible, to Google analytics track the http://doamin.com/aa.png, and the image when open on other sites.

I am from Brazil, so if you are too, answer in Portuguese please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics works from some javascript loaded into the page to call back to google with "here I am, I'm on a page doing the following...". Since the script isn't in an image, it can't do the same. You'll have to just analyse your web logs. There are [plenty of tools for doing so](http://www.google.com/search?q=web%20log%20analysers), or you can grep the logs, write a custom app that finds the info you need, etc. It won't be as rich or user-friendly as analytics, but there's still a goodly amount you can find out.

Comment: Today is Sunday and I am with some free time. I translate your response to pt-br as asked by the OP. (Not sure if this is allowed in SO, I mean, other language than english...)

Comment: Not sure either, but since my Portuguese goes as far as "obrigado" and "de nada", I wasn't going to be able to.

Comment: @devundef Might as well leave it in. It's not doing any harm, after all.

Comment: I've never seen other languages here in SO, anyway you're right, I'll leave it...